# In the Chrome Console Source tab, how can I find where a script is called?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a console error when I view an app I am developing locally. The error takes place within by a third-party script hosted on an external domain.

The trouble is, I can't determine what part of the app locally is calling this this script. Either it's cleverly disguised in a local file or perhaps a chrome extension is calling it? It seems there must be a feature in the console that can tell me where in the stack this script is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a breakpoint on the line where the error is thrown, and then when the debugger pauses, you will be able to see the Call Stack on the right pane under the Sources tab. You can add a breakpoint either by clicking on the line number or by adding a `debugger;` statement into your source code.

[image: Call Stack]

If you find yourself stepping into 3rd party libraries, you can right-click and select 'Blackbox script', and then next time the debugger runs through the app code, you will only break inside your own code.

[image: Blackboxing]

Comment: ah-ha—that's what I was looking for. Thanks!